# Data directory permissions on host for Clickhouse installation via docker

Tags: clickhouse

My setup for clickhouse is via docker (https://hub.docker.com/r/yandex/clickhouse-server/~/dockerfile/). Currently, I am running some issues when mounting the data directory (/var/lib/clickhouse) from the container to the host machine as I want to persist the data outside of the container runtime.

Since the docker process is responsible for creating the directories on the host (these directories for /var/lib/clickhouse do not exist until running docker with a -v flag), what are the permissions and/or directory structure I should provision on my host instance?

I am bumping into something like:`Application: Access to file denied: /var/lib/clickhouse/data`. My explicit file mounts are: `/var/lib/clickhouse` and `/var/lib/clickhouse/tmp` as prescribed in the configuration file. But since the clickhouse server process seems to create more directories, the docker process is being "rejected" when trying to create more processes.

I *could* explicitly mount the /data, etc but this makes an assumption that is outside of the configuration. Also, this *does* work if I give generous permissions top `/var/clickhouse` like: `chmod 777 /var/clickhouse` but wanted to make sure this was best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see in [https://hub.docker.com/r/yandex/clickhouse-server/~/dockerfile/](https://hub.docker.com/r/yandex/clickhouse-server/%7E/dockerfile/)
you can try run on host OS.

```
docker run --rm -i --entrypoint /bin/sh yandex/clickhouse-server -c id clickhouse
```

> uid=105(clickhouse) gid=106(clickhouse) groups=106(clickhouse)

after getting id, you can run on host OS as:

```
chown -R 105:106 /var/lib/clickhouse
```

Answer (score 2):

i was able to run Clickhouse in a docker container with no problems using Docker Volumes instead of bind mounts.
In my case, i was running: Docker Desktop on Windows 11 with WSL 2. There is a well known bug on how WSL handle permissions set on the linux side and how they are reflected on the Windows filesystem. In short, permissions set in linux dont work well.

Using Docker Volumes are working for me

Comment: What do you mean by Docker volumes?

Comment: The default way to link to a local volume is using binds in Docker but the most recomended way is to create a volume that is an internal way in Docker. You can read how to do this in here: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/