# Can't INSERT INTO ClickHouse DB due to Insufficient permissions: /var/lib/clickhouse/data/

Tags: docker, docker-compose, clickhouse

I created an instance of a ClickHouse DB in a container through docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  ch:
    image: yandex/clickhouse-server
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - '/mnt/c/DevTools/source/storm/clickhouse_setup/data/ch:/var/lib/clickhouse/'
      - './ch_configs:/etc/clickhouse-server/'
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
      - 8123:8123
    ulimits:
      nofile: 262144
    
  client:
    image: yandex/clickhouse-client
    volumes:
      - './client-config.xml:/etc/clickhouse-client/config.xml'
```

I can access it and find the database that I created, but when I run

```sql
INSERT INTO simple_people (id, first_name, last_name) VALUES(1,'david','lo')
```

I get this response:

```sh
Query id: 46ef1af8-5728-425e-87f5-511f7e0e79d1
Received exception from server (version 20.12.3):
Code: 1000. DB::Exception: Received from ch:9000. DB::Exception: Access to file denied: insufficient permissions: /var/lib/clickhouse/data/registry/simple_people/tmp_insert_1_2_2_0.
1 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.068 sec.
```

**How do I get permission to INSERT INTO?**

*Notes:*

I have no issues running:

```sql
SELECT * FROM simple_people
```

I'm on WSL: Ubuntu-20.04

Comment: Hi, please don't post pics of your code. You can use 3 backticks before and after your codeblock to insert the code in your post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Data directory permissions on host for Clickhouse installation via docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46917533/data-directory-permissions-on-host-for-clickhouse-installation-via-docker)

Comment: try to give write-permission for current user to folder with data: *chmod -R u=rw ./data/ch*.

Comment: @vladimir Thank you for your input. I ran the command chmod -R u=rw ./data/ch without issues but it still wouldn't let me access the file.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of WSL + docker.

Try full path, instead of ./data

Comment: Thanks for your input, but by entering the full path instead of ."/data.." didnt do it.

Comment: Probably it's unsolvable then. Try to install/run CH in WSL without docker. Or use VirtualBox. The issue is not in CH.

Answer (score 0):

I installed clickhouse directly on WSL Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows server 2019 without docker and faced the same issue. In my case I was trying to insert data into a table with ClickHouse storage policy setup so that all data would be stored in /mnt/f/clickhouse (F:\clickhouse on windows). The error I got was :

```
DB::Exception: Access to file denied: insufficient permissions: /mnt/f/clickhouse/store/1e6/1e69cad8-25a1-4ec5-ab5b-fb32d73b7c8c/tmp_insert_all_2_2_0
```

The fix for the issue was to enable the metadata feature on WSL which syncs permissions between linux and windows by remounting the F: drive with the feature enabled. And then recreate the clickhouse folder if it is already existing.

```
sudo umount /mnt/f
sudo mount -t drvfs F: /mnt/f -o metadata
```

### Extra information

If you have any questions about how to setup a storage policy on clickhouse to choose the location of your data. Below is the contents of my /etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/storage.xml

```
<yandex>
  <storage_configuration>
    <disks>
      <!--
          default disk is special, it always
          exists even if not explicitly
          configured here, but you can't change
          it's path here (you should use <path>
          on top level config instead)
      -->
      <default>
         <!--
             You can reserve some amount of free space
             on any disk (including default) by adding
             keep_free_space_bytes tag
         -->
         <keep_free_space_bytes>1024</keep_free_space_bytes>
      </default>

      <mnt_f>
         <!--
         disk path must end with a slash,
         folder should be writable for clickhouse user
         -->
         <path>/mnt/f/clickhouse/</path>
      </mnt_f>
    </disks>
    <policies>
      <mnt_f_only> <!-- name for new storage policy -->
        <volumes>  
          <mnt_f_volume> <!-- name of volume -->
            <!-- 
                we have only one disk in that volume  
                and we reference here the name of disk
                as configured above in <disks> section
            -->
            <disk>mnt_f</disk>
          </mnt_f_volume>
        </volumes>
      </mnt_f_only>
    </policies>
  </storage_configuration>
</yandex>
```

Choose the storage policy when creating the table:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    EventId String,
    EventName Nullable(String),
) ENGINE = MergeTree()
ORDER BY EventId
SETTINGS storage_policy = 'mnt_f_only';
```